# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

We're here for yet another year! And with that comes yet another edition of our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- your ventrilo server
- the site's twitter account
- indie games that are awesome, but people might not know about
- game servers or gaming nights
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/8040).

Answer (score 34):

[image: Pay what you want, support charity, get incredible games: The Humble Bundle]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Child's Play - Give games to kids in hospital]

Comment: Shouldn't "hospital" be pluralized?

Comment: @Sean Not in British English, not sure about American, though if so then I'm happy to change it.

Comment: @fredley American English would definitely be "in hospitals" or perhaps more colloquially "in the hospital." "In hospital" sounds really weird to me—I assumed it was a typo til I read your comment.

Comment: Yep, likewise. If dlras2's replacement works in British English, then all good, but if not, I think the tie goes to the incumbent. (Another aside: I'd flip the lines of the subtitle to "It makes a difference when...") Thanks for putting this together.

Comment: @Sean Pluralised!

Answer (score 19):

[image: The Kingdom of Loathing: An Adventurer is You!]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Robotics StackExchange (Image by Evan-Amos)]

Comment: Thanks to [Evan-Amos](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Evan-Amos) for sharing the image [via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NES-ROB.jpg) under [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).

Comment: Since this is gaming why not use some robots from the [world of gaming](http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121221184924/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/e/e0/GLaDOS.png)?

Comment: @boo That is the [original Gaming Robot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.O.B.)!

Comment: @BillyMailman I stand corrected!

Comment: @MarkBooth It's ok, one robotics ad is enough!

Answer (score 15):

[image: Raspberry Pi StackExchange - What will you do with yours?]

Comment: If people have a Raspberry Pi project that you think would be appropriate on this ad let me know.

Comment: MAME would be a good example

Answer (score 14):

[image: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/]

Comment: Open to comments and criticisms.

Comment: I like the idea, but the text is very badly aliased and hard to read.

Comment: [Here's my take](http://i.imgur.com/UqZE5cf.png)

Comment: @boo Wow.  Love it.  Can I suggest we put your picture up instead of mine?

Comment: Done it for you!

Comment: The font is not very good for this size. Also poor outline and shadow work, but mainly the font is at fault. And isn't there a better ME-inspiring image?

Comment: @user1306322 Feel free to suggest different images/fonts, or make your own.

Comment: @fredley nah, I'm good.

Comment: @user1306322 I disagree.  I think the font is a good pick.  The URL could maybe be a bit larger, but the image is a link for it anyway.

Comment: [Why not advertise both ways?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3292/1881)

Comment: Isn't that a copyright violation?

Comment: I don't understand the text of this ad. At all.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Mass Effect is a game that includes elements from both Science Fiction and Fantasy genres.  Think of it like a crossroad where 2 worlds collide.  scifi.SE does both of those.  They even have a few [mass effect questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect) over there.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Anime and Manga StackExchange]

Comment: It might just be because I am on my phone, but I find that text hard to read.

Comment: @AshleyNunn I updated the text to hopefully be easier to read.

Comment: We're trying to coordinate community ads for Anime SE on [Anime meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/761/community-ads-on-the-network-2014-edition). It would be good if you could post this ad there. BTW thanks for designing this, I (and I'm sure many others) appreciate it.

Comment: @LoganMaingi Your wish is my command: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/762/1651

Comment: 0.5 pixel white outline would make the text much more readable

Comment: @user1306322 half of a pixel? I'm not sure that is possible

Comment: @Batophobia everything is possible with a lil' bit of imagination. Or computers. Especially both. Use 1 pixel outer stroke with 50% opacity. But that might not even make for the best − experiment and find the look you find most suitable.

Answer (score 11):

[image: The Indie Royale: Grab awesome games and music!]

Comment: Somebody feel free to edit this to add some text or something, my typography skills stink.

Comment: Unfamiliar with IR, so maybe there's more appropriate text? http://i.imgur.com/CzppsHS.png

Comment: I would even add some more flavour text like "New bundles every other week."

Comment: @MBraedley [How's this](http://i.imgur.com/bmqR4VN.png)

Comment: @boo perfect! (15 chars)

Comment: Thanks guys!  Definitely better with the text.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Find and play the latest indie games at IndieStatik]

Answer (score 6):

[image: World In Progress]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. This time with the right logo the first time around!

Comment: I do not think we should run this one. It was our least clicked ad last year, and in my opinion our Twitter feed is not really representative of this community.

Comment: Ha! I didn't even know there was a twitter :p serves me right for never looking at the ads ;)

Answer (score -4):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: What is wrong with the robotics ad?

Comment: I don't have a problem with it, but I would suggest making it a bit more gaming-relevant.  After all, Arqade is a gaming site.  Maybe something like [Machinarium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machinarium), [CL4P-TP from Borderlands](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Claptrap), [Portal Robots](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Co-op), or even the classic [R.O.B.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.O.B.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Batophobia, The unencumbered R.O.B. image might be an option. I prefer not to use copyrighted images wherever possible.

Comment: @Batophobia. - Let me know what you think of my [latest suggestion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8066/8557).

Answer (score -9):

[image: robotics stack exchange]